# SurfaceHolder confusion

Tags: android

i am using surfaceholder but their is confusion between the two
what will be better to use

differentiate between SurfaceHolder.callback vs SurfaceHolder.callback2

Answer (score 1):

Both callbacks do different things:

[SurfaceHolder.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html) notifies you when the surface is created, changed, or destroyed.

[SurfaceHolder.Callback2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback2.html) on top of this notifies you when your application should redraw the content of its surface.

So when you don't draw to the surface manually and can't trigger the drawing somehow (e.g. when using the MediaPlayer API), you don't need Callback2.

Answer (score 1):

**[SurfaceHolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html)**

Abstract interface to someone holding a display surface. Allows you to control the surface size and format, edit the pixels in the surface, and monitor changes to the surface. This interface is typically available through the SurfaceView class.

[**SurfaceHolder.Callback**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html)

A client may implement this interface to receive information about changes to the surface. When used with a SurfaceView, the Surface being held is only available between calls to surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder) and surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder). The Callback is set with SurfaceHolder.addCallback method.

**[SurfaceHolder.Callback2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback2.html)**

Additional callbacks that can be received for SurfaceHolder.Callback.

i used above text explanation from [developer site](http://developer.android.com/index.html)